# How to display facebook request dialog in front of game

Tags: facebook, dialog, request, unity-game-engine

I've got a Unity game on Facebook and when I click in-game on the send request button the request dialog gets stuck behind the game.

[image]

Comment: It's is a Unity game, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Facebook games or Unity but it seems to me that Unity frames are always rendered above everything else, at least in Google Chrome. Perhaps an adequate solution would be to hide the Unity frame if that's possible? Also [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/30374-Unity3D-rendering-compatibility-with-Facebook) at Unity3D from two years ago addresses the same problem. Hope it helps.